# Filtering through another dataframe to create new columns in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes:

`df1`

```
id |tier |event_date
233|1    |2014-01-20
234|1    |2015-02-12
235|2    |2015-02-12
```

`df2`

```
id |join_date |stop_date
233|2013-03-12|2015-04-01
233|2016-03-12|2017-04-01
235|2013-03-12|2016-04-01
```

I want to create two columns in `df2`, `has_tier_1`, `has_tier_2`

For every row in `df2` I want to see if there is a matching row based on `id` in `df1`. It is possible to have multiple matching rows in `df1`.:

If there is a matching row then I want to check `event_date` in `df1` is between the `join_date` and `stop_date` in `df2`. If so then then based on the `tier`, it will be 1 in the appropriate column.

The goal is for `df2` to look like this:

```
id |join_date |stop_date |has_tier_1| has_tier_2
233|2013-03-12|2015-04-01|    1     |  0
233|2016-03-12|2017-04-01|    0     |  0
235|2013-03-12|2016-04-01|    0     |  1
```

I created this function:

```
def create_columns(x):
    x[has_tier_1] == 0
    x[has_tier_2] == 0
    if x['id'] in df1['id']:
        if x['join_date'] <= df1['event_date'] <= x['stop_date']:
            if df1['tier'] == '1':
                return has_tier_1 == 1
            elif df1['tier'] == '2':
                return has_tier_2 == 1
            else:
                return x[has_tier_1], x[has_tier_2] 

    else:
        return x[has_tier_1], x[has_tier_2]
```

I applied:

```
df1.apply(create_columns)
```

However, I am nor getting the right results. Please help on how I can achieve this.

Comment: there is no tier 2 in 234. what's the logic behind assigning 1 to has_tier_2?

Comment: that was a typo sorry about that

Comment: doesnt look like anything changed. has_tier_2 should be all 0s, unless u have a different logic for it?

Comment: The logic is if the id matches and the df1.event_date is between df2.start_date and df2.end_date then based on the tier the appropriate tier has 1

Comment: cool seen ur update

Answer (score 0):

pandas' [merge asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) method comes in handy here, as it allows us to merge columns based on distance. the direction is set to forward, ensuring that the value on the left is less than or equal to the value on the right. Have a look at the link for more guidance.

Test the code below and see if it covers your use case:

```
res = (pd.merge_asof(df1,df,
                     by='id',
                     left_on='join_date',
                     right_on='event_date',
                     direction='forward')
       .fillna(0)
       .drop('event_date',axis=1)
       .assign(has_tier_1 = lambda x: np.where(x.tier == 1, 1, 0),
               has_tier_2 = lambda x: np.where(x.tier == 2, 1, 0)
              )
       .sort_values('id')
      )
res


    id  join_date   stop_date   tier    has_tier_1  has_tier_2
0   233 2013-03-12  2015-04-01  1.0        1           0
2   233 2016-03-12  2017-04-01  0.0        0           0
1   235 2013-03-12  2016-04-01  2.0        0           1
```